# Partial differential equations related to diffusion

Tags: partial-differential-equations, boundary-value-problem

**Setting:** I am studying solutions of the partial differential equation

$w_t - cw_y-D(w_{xx}+w_{yy})=0 $,

where $c$ and $D$ are real constants. The domain of the solutions shall be $(x,y)\in (0,L) \times { (0,L)}$ and the initial condition is $w(x,y,0)=f(x,y)$. I furthermore demand Dirichlet boundary conditions $w(0,y)=w(L,y)=w(x,0)=0$ and  $w(x,L)=u_o=const$.

Let $w(x,y,t)=u(x,y,t)+v(x,y)$ be a solution of (1).

**Question:** Under which conditions can I find a function $v(x,y)$ such that $u(x,y,t)$ satisfies homogeneous boundary conditions?

Answer (score 0):

$v(x,y)$ is the steady state solution, that is for $w_t=0$, so that:

$$cv_y+D(v_{xx}+v_{yy})=0$$
Assume:

$$v(x,y)=X(x)Y(y)$$
Separation of variables:
$$cXY'+D(X''Y+XY'')=0$$
$$\frac{c}{D}\frac{Y'}{Y}+\frac{X''}{X}+\frac{Y''}{Y}=0$$
$$\frac{c}{D}\frac{Y'}{Y}+\frac{Y''}{Y}=-\frac{X''}{X}=-m^2$$
$$\frac{c}{D}\frac{Y'}{Y}+\frac{Y''}{Y}=-m^2\tag{1}$$
$$-\frac{X''}{X}=-m^2\tag{2}$$

Try to solve ODEs $(1)$ and $(2)$ using your boundary conditions.

However, the boundary conidions $w(0,y)=w(L,y)=w(x,0)=0$ don't make much sense because $w$ is a function of $(x,y,t)$.

Similarly $w(x,L)=u_0=const$ appears incomplete.